# Get around Windows compatibility link directories

Tags: c#, .net, windows, ntfs

Windows 7 has a number of directories that have names from ancient times and cannot be accessed. I mean directories like "C:\Documents and Settings" and "C:\Dokumente und Einstellungen" where the real folder is "C:\Users". Another one is "C:\Programme" on localised systems. These directories show up when iterating all directories with `Directory.GetDirectories` but cannot be accessed. When trying to access them, an `UnauthorizedAccessException` is thrown. I could catch it, but it causes extra time that slows down my scan. I'd rather avoid looking into those fake directories in the first place. (I'm wondering why they're even there and whether I could just delete them, but that's another question.)

So what's a good way to detect such traps before actually falling into them? I guess it's some kind of link, but there's different kinds of links (and stuff from the guts of NTFS no worldly user can create themselves) and still I wouldn't know how to detect that from code.

I know that I still need to handle that exception, but if I already know in advance that an operation won't work I'd like to not do it to keep things fast. Disk scans are slow enough already.

My code is not supposed to run with administrative privileges, nor is it expecting to find anything useful in those linked directories.

Comment: Catching the exception may cause extra time, but does that have _serious_ impact on your execution time? It's entirely possible that the code you'd need to avoid this would actually cost more than just accepting that you'll have to deal with the exception.

Comment: There's a deny everyone ACE in the DACL that prevents listing them. But they can still be traversed, e.g. `dir "%SystemDrive%\Documents and Settings\%USERNAME%"`.

Comment: Stay away from any directory that has the Hidden and System attributes.

Comment: System and Hidden attributes is actually a good note, as all of these unwelcoming directories have those attributes, and also others I don't want to look into. This seems like the easiest check.

Comment: You definitely shouldn't delete those directories.  Windows might or might not need them, but plenty of third-party applications do.

Answer (score 2):

`DirectoryInfo.FileAttributes`contains the `ReparsePoint`attribute in the case of a symbolic linked folder:

```
// Code from LinqPad, not sure it compiles in IDE:
DirectoryInfo di = new DirectoryInfo(@"c:\documents and settings");
Console.WriteLine("{0}", di.Attributes);  // Hidden, System, Directory, ReparsePoint, NotContentIndexed
```

Comment: But, would the OP want to skip all reparse points, or just some of them that Microsoft has created?  I bet other reparse points would be fine to go down.

Comment: I don't know, I've never knowingly created a reparse point for myself or seen them used in practice for anything besides these types of aliased folders....

Comment: I've used them extensively to mount volumes inside other volumes, move data around from under programs with hardcoded paths, and for software deployments with easy rollback in my production environment.  If OP is writing some software for himself, he could get away ignoring reparse points, but if he's selling software to others, I would be pissed if it didn't work in my environment because I used a fairly basic filesystem feature.

Comment: The problem isn't the attributes or that it's a junction or symbolic link. None of that matters. There's a deny everyone ACE that prevents listing these junctions; they're only there to be traversed.  If you wanted to LBYL you'd have to call `GetFileSecurity` and `AccessCheck` -- or whatever the equivalent is in .NET.

Comment: @dsolimano: depends what the program is doing.  In my experience, if you're iterating through a directory tree, skipping reparse points is almost always the correct behaviour.  (Though in some cases it may be wise to allow the user to overrule you.)  PS - possibly amusing example; a security bug I discovered in an old version of Windows (can't remember now whether it was 2000 or XP).  If the user created a junction point from their user profile to, say, system32, when they logged out and Windows deleted their profile it would follow the junction point and delete everything there too.

Answer (score 1):

If performance is your goal, you could do better than recursively iterating folders - you can read the MFT directly.  It's not blissfully simple, but it is really fast.  Here's a [tutorial](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsdesktop/CCS-LABS-C-Accessing-the-d317805c/sourcecode?fileId=60931&pathId=14261056) for doing the dirty work if you're interested.

Comment: Interesting approach, I've put it on my list of things to try out.